# why does escape character \b shows an unknown character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, python-3.5, unicode-escapes

i have a simple line of code

```
 print("Hello \bWorld!")
```

and the output instead of ***HelloWorld!*** is

[image]

what is the problem ? im using python 3.5. i took the code from w3school.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *console output* is incapeable of displaying the `'\b'`. This has nothing to do with python.

It works in Visual Studio: You can verify it by setting a breakpoint in your debugger and inspect the value (most IDEs have UTF-8 support) - the windows console f.e. has not.

Debugging output in Visual Studio:

[image: debugger output]

vs. console output in windows:

[image: output in console]

and (here it looks like yours)

[image: output in output]

for

```
k = "Hello \bWorld!"
print(k)
```

Comment: thanks for answer . isnt \b suppose to erase the last character before it ?or im misunderstood? why in the output space is still there?there is an space and and unknown char. and picture is for pycharm IDE .  and also even if i write the "Hello \bWorld!" in a file instead of printing and open it with app like notepad++ even there its not displayed correctly .

Comment: @mike If you do `with open("f.txt","w") as f: f.write("Hello \bWorld")` you file with contain exactly that .. a space followed by a `'\b'` - it does not miracuously remove the space and the \b (and before/after then the remainder of your string) from your string before writing. If you _print_  `"Hello \bWorld"` in a compatible shell, it will only print `"HelloWorld"` - see _console output in windows_ above. Your IDE decided to display the full string instead without applying the \b to the space.

Comment: @ Patrick Artner another question . i would be thankful if you would clarify this for me. suppose i have text file with some text in it if i do ***write("\b")*** is it suppose to delete the last character in the file ?

Comment: @Mike no - it will write an additional character to the file, which is `'\b'` (or binary \x08 )

Answer (score 1):

```
\b
```

ASCII backspace ( BS ) removes previous character in Python 3.x:

```
print("ab\bc")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ac
```

In your case its not something related to Python but the console itself.

As I get:

```
print("Hello \bWorld")   # HelloWorld
```

[pyFiddle](https://onlinegdb.com/SkA6BlmFU)

[Python Escape Characters](http://python-ds.com/python-3-escape-sequences)